# Import mutiple files with one import via Webpack Plugin

Tags: webpack, srcset

I saw the [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) ([source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/8a7597aa6eb2eef66a8f9db3a0c49bcb96022a94/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin.js)), and wanted to do the same but for images srcsets.

I import images like so: `import image from './image.jpg'`, but would also like to handle @2x and @3x images without having to import them explicitly (exactly like Metro Bundler/React Native).

I have this pseudo Webpack Plugin:

```
const path = require('path');

const getSrcSet = (string, number) => string.split('.').join(`@${number}x.`);

class SrcSetPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {    
    const resourceRegExp = /\.jpe?g|png$/i;

    compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap('SrcSetPlugin', (nmf) => {
      nmf.hooks.beforeResolve.tap('SrcSetPlugin', (result) => {
        if (!result) return;
        if (resourceRegExp.test(result.request)) {
          // pseudo-code to also import other srcSets
          result.request2 = getSrcSet(result.request, 2);
          result.request3 = getSrcSet(result.request, 3);
        }
        return result;
      });
      nmf.hooks.afterResolve.tap('SrcSetPlugin', (result) => {
        if (!result) return;
        if (resourceRegExp.test(result.resource)) {
          console.log(result);
          process.exit(0);

          // pseudo-code to also resolve other srcSets
          result.resource2 = path.resolve(
            path.dirname(result.resource),
            getSrcSet(result.resource.split('/').slice(-1), 2),
          );
          result.resource3 = path.resolve(
            path.dirname(result.resource),
            getSrcSet(result.resource.split('/').slice(-1), 3),
          );
        }
        return result;
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = SrcSetPlugin;
```

Is there a way to tell Webpack to process multiple files for one userRequest?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Input

```
import image from './image.jpg';
```

Output

```
console.log(image);

> { 1x: '/images/image.jpg', 2x: '/images/image@2x.jpg', 3x: '/images/image@3x.jpg' }
```

Comment: I think this would be better handled as a loader and not a plugin.

[Responsive-loader](https://github.com/herrstucki/responsive-loader) does something similar to this already (but instead of finding and including the different sizes, it just resizes them down to the different sizes), so that might be a good place to look and see how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I also tried with a loader, and could access the file content and the path (`this.resourcePath`) but could not really see how to tell Webpack "please also import these files like the others"

Comment: You should be able to just export the file, but attach new properties to it as you pass it along. I believe there's also some trickery to adding assets to the whole webpack pipeline to ensure they get picked up by other plugins (but not loaders, since loaders only work on the actual "thing" as it's imported).

So if you are writing your loader to be used AFTER the file loader, then you would accept the object the file loader returns, and you would attach properties to it and pass it along. If you are intending to replace the file loader, then you need to replicate its features.

Comment: Interesting. I will look in this direction. Thanks a lot!